# Can These Types of Curve be Differentiable in their Parameters?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, economics

This question arises from economic research attempting to model and estimate demand curves relating the quantity consumed $Q$ of goods to their price $P$. Assume $P > 0$, $Q \ge 0$, and as $P$ increases, $Q$ smoothly decreases when $Q > 0$ and, if it reaches $0$, remains at $0$ for all higher $P$.  It is desired to express $Q$ as a function of $P$, the function being differentiable with respect to its parameters over the full range of $P$, and ideally linear in its parameters (to facilitate estimation by regression).

When $P$ is sufficiently high it is expected that $Q$ will either be $0$ or very close to $0$.  There seem to be three cases:

1. The curve is asymptotic to the $P$ axis.  This is straightforward, e.g.  $Y = \dfrac{b}{P}$ or $\ln Y =  a – bP$ are differentiable with respect to the parameters $a$, $b$.
2. There is some value $k$ of $P$ such that $Q = 0$ when $P \ge k$ and $Q > 0$ when $P < k$, and the curve is smooth at $k$.
3. As for 2 above, but kinked at $k$.

On the assumption that $k$ is unknown and must be considered one of the parameters, is there a way to model cases 2 and/or 3 with functions which are differentiable with respect to their parameters?

For case 2, I considered the function:

$Y = b(k - P)^2$  if  $P < k$ and $Y = 0$ if $P \ge k$

However this does not work: it’s differentiable with respect to $b$ but not with respect to $k$.

Comment: @Andrew Ostergaard  Thank you for your edit.  Evidently I wasn't very familiar with Latex when I posted this 8 years ago.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for posting this question. When posts get edited they get moved to the top of the list of active posts. So perhaps the edit will help this post get noticed, and hopefully answered.